# What is the derivative of $x \mapsto\frac{ (x+3)^4}{\sqrt{x^2+5}}$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I want to find the derivative of the function $$x \mapsto \frac{ (x+3)^4}{\sqrt{x^2+5}}$$ This is a fraction with $(x+3)$ to the $4$th power as the numerator and the square root of the function $x$ squared plus $5$ as the denominator. Can you please provide a step-by-step solution and explanation as well?

Comment: What have you tried? Do you know the quotient and chain rules?

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) is a short note about posting mathematical notation on this site, with links to more detailed features of $\LaTeX$.  Questions that largely consist of merely stating a problem and asking Readers to solve it for you are often poorly received here (and may be closed pending your adding more context).

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to MSE!

The given function, $f(x) = \frac{ (x+3)^4}{\sqrt{x^2+5}}$

We here need to use power rule and $\frac{U}{V}$ rule

The $\frac{U}{V}$ rule (U,V are two functions) when differentiated you get $\frac{UV'-VU'}{V^2}$

The power rule says for a function of type $V^n$ when differentiated you get $nV^{n-1}$

Using the above two,

$f'(x)$=$\frac{dy}{dx}$=$\frac{4(x+3)^3 \sqrt{x^2+5}-(x+3)^4\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x^2+5}}}{x^2+5}$

You can simplify from here

Answer (score 0):

Given that $f\left(x\right)=\frac{\left(x+3\right)^4}{\sqrt{x^2+5}}$, one way of finding $f'\left(x\right)$ involves the use of **logarithmic differentiation**.

$f\left(x\right)=\frac{\left(x+3\right)^4}{\sqrt{x^2+5}}$

$y=\frac{\left(x+3\right)^4}{\sqrt{x^2+5}}$

$\ln y=\ln\frac{\left(x+3\right)^4}{\sqrt{x^2+5}}$

$\ln y=\ln\left(x+3\right)^4-\ln\sqrt{x^2+5}$

$\ln y=4\ln\left(x+3\right)-\frac{\ln\left(x^2+5\right)}{2}$

$D_x\left[\ln y\right]=D_x\left[4\ln\left(x+3\right)-\frac{\ln\left(x^2+5\right)}{2}\right]$

$\frac{y'}{y}=\frac{4}{x+3}-\frac{x}{x^2+5}$

$y'=f'\left(x\right)=\frac{\left(x+3\right)^4}{\sqrt{x^2+5}}\left(\frac{4}{x+3}-\frac{x}{x^2+5}\right)$

Feel free to further simplify the answer above if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

we can use the qoutient rule and then chain rule plus some simplifications which leads us to the final answer !
[image file jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwsZb.jpg)

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.